# How can I count how many buttons have been pressed in my windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I found a snippet of code from a similar question but it didn't quite fit my implementation, and I couldn't figure out how to adapt it to my game. I have fifteen buttons and I need to be able to count the number of buttons pressed for each turn of a game. I am a very much a beginner with a limited knowledge of programming. I need to be able to count button presses, and then have the method restart at each players turn.

```
private void label1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int count++;
}
```

I created mouse click event but I get an error when trying to increment my count `int`.

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: @qwr I have updated; Didn't mean to leave that out.

Comment: you declared count as local. declare it as member of form class. it will work.plus syntax is: int count;count++;

Comment: Two ways 1) use a control button which is customized control and on every click the `Static` Variable needs to increment within the form. 2) you needs to use the pre render command which renders the control on every event command, there you needs to write if command name is click even then while rendering you need to increase the count value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this class, then you can use `ButtonEx` instead of `Button` in your designer

```
public class ButtonEx : Button
{
    public int ClickCount { get; private set; }
    public ButtonEx()
    {
        this.Click += (s, e) => { ++this.ClickCount; };
    }

    public void ResetPressCount()
    {
        this.ClickCount = 0;
    }
}
```

I see you have used label instead of button in you application
you can just use this for label

```
public class LabelEx : Label
{
    public int ClickCount { get; private set; }
    public LabelEx()
    {
        this.MouseClick += (s, e) => { ++this.ClickCount; };
    }

    public void ResetPressCount()
    {
        this.ClickCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the "(s, e)" do?

Comment: `(s, e) => { //code }` is a function that accepts two parameters (s and e) and do //code, compiler will find out that types of `s` is `object` and type of `e` is `EventArgs`

Comment: @JasonB have a look at [Func<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on syntax like `(s, e) =>`

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix.`//all these inside form class`

```
  //declare count as integer, you can also initialize it ( int count=startvalue;)
   int count;

   //if you want to understand read topic about delegates and events
   private void label1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
      ++count;
   }

   //call reset()  when you want to reset
   private void reset(){
         count=0;
   }
```

**Also check**
[stackoverflow: c# Resources, Books](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info)

Comment: This change worked.  Is there a way to rewrite this to reset count at each players turn? @qwr

Answer (score 2):

Because `int count++` is Invalid Syntax.

The proper way to create an Increment integer value is;

```
private int count = 0;
private void label1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    count++;
}
```

and to reset the integer `count` you need to make a reset button or include the `count = 0;` in your desire method.